# What is a Git repository's real name when defining a remote?

Tags: git, github, repository

Take a Git repo named `myrepo`.  What is it's real name/filename when referring to it as a remote?

I ask because I've noticed that for Github you can use either:

- `https://github.com/lightcc/myrepo`
- `https://github.com/lightcc/myrepo.git`

I've also seen cases where local repos point directly to the `.git` folder:

- `/c/code/myrepo/.git`

And other cases where the repo is locally called by the repo folder name like `myrepo.git`, such as:

- `/c/code/myrepo.git`

That last one might be the real folder name for a `--bare` repo, but I'm not sure, I haven't created a local bare repo before.

### So what is the correct name to use when trying to setup a remote (i.e. what name is correct to use in a `git remote add` statement)?

---

**Edit:** Updated question as the answers weren't what I expected - I am trying to understand how to setup a repo as a remote, or even setup a local repo properly so that it can become a remote in the future.  So this has more to do with the `git remote add` command syntax.  I get that in English we would just say it is named `myrepo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the server.

GitHub and others will alias the non-`.git` version to `.git`.

If you're running your own Git server, and name the bare repository with `.git` (as recommended for bare repos), then you will be required to use `.git`.

Comment: For the second point, do you mean name the bare repo with `myrepo.git`, as in the `.git` is used as an extension to the folder name? So then the repo would just directly be the contents of this folder, which would be equivalent to a normal `myrepo/.git` folder?  This makes sense. If I understand right, your answer is that I have to use the full filename of the git folder (when pointing to a remote with `git remote add`, unless their is an alias/symbolic link which points to the full filename on the server (or locally).

Comment: Yep, you've exactly got it.

Answer (score 3):

> What is its real name/filename when referring to it as a remote?

When referring to a repository as a remote, the URL at which the remote repository is reachable does not actually matter. What matters then is the name *you give it* when adding the remote:

```
git remote add <remote-name> <remote-url>
```

You can choose really any name there. Two common names which kind of have their own inherent meaning (although that’s not a *rule*) are `origin` for the default remote you cloned from and usually pull from or push to, and `upstream` for an upstream repository that your `origin` is a fork of (so usually, the workflow would be pull from `upstream`, do work, push to `origin` and send pull request).

As for the URL, this really depends on what kind of system you are interacting with: In general, the URL has to be valid. For file systems, this means that the path must exist. So `/path/to/repo.git` and `/path/to/repo/.git` would be two very different things.

In general, the `.git` folder has a name, when its a *bare repository* (a repository without a working directory). In that case, the repository name is the name before the `.git`. So for `/path/to/repo.git`, `repo` would be the name.

When it’s just `/path/to/repo/.git`, then we’re dealing with a non-bare repository and the working directory is at `/path/to/repo/`. Its name would *also* be `repo`.

For actual URLs, it’s up to the server to decide what to accept, whether they require a `.git` extension or not. Most repository hosters (like GitHub and Bitbucket) will accept either, so just choose whatever you like (or whatever the web UI puts into your clipboard when you click “clone”).