# Git - branching vs multiple remotes

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to git and its best practices. I was reading through the documentation when I came upon this example:

```
$ cd grit
$ git remote -v
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (fetch)
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (push)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (fetch)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (push)
defunkt   https://github.com/defunkt/grit (fetch)
defunkt   https://github.com/defunkt/grit (push)
koke      git://github.com/koke/grit.git (fetch)
koke      git://github.com/koke/grit.git (push)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (fetch)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (push)
```

The document goes on to mention:

> This means we can pull contributions from any of these users pretty
>   easily. We may additionally have permission to push to one or more of
>   these, though we can’t tell that here.

What would be the benefits for me (or the team) to have multiple copies of the same codebase in separate remote repos, and what is the difference between doing this and simply having a separate branch for everyone (which is probably poor practice anyway, but having separate repos seems even worse)?

Comment: If anything, it makes things more complicated. On a *technical* level, all repositories are more or less the same, but more often than not it makes sense to define one as the central repository.

Comment: Having [a separate branch for everyone](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is actually good practice, by the way.

Comment: @user3151902: thanks, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that every clone comes with its own set of branches already. So `bakkdoor/master` and `cho45/master` are two different branches. They may have the same local name (`master`) and may have the same remote tracking branch (`origin/master`, both of them pushing to the `origin` remote) but they are still separate branches that need to be managed individually.

So effectively, by working with multiple repositories, you are just doing branches on a locally more distant level. But the techniques are pretty much the same.

Of course, what you are actually talking about is the [distributed workflow](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) a team uses. The classic one is the centralized workflow, where you have one blessed repository in the middle that everyone has access to. This works well with teams that knows what they are doing. Everybody is expected to push the right things, and in well coordinated teams, this works very well.

For open source projects, the common workflow is the “integration manager workflow” though. A limited amount of developers have write access to the blessed repository. Developers are expected to publish their proposed changes elsewhere (usually in their own public repository) and then propose pull requests to get those merged in. The big benefit is that this works for every kind of team: As the access to the central repository is very limited, nobody will be able to mess that one up. Developers, even untrusted ones, can just publish their changes in their own public repository—if they mess up there, well, it’s their repository, they can do whatever they want.

The other benefit is that this gives a clearer picture of what’s “canon” for a project. Developers can experiment in their own repository and change everything without that impacting others in the central repository. So there’s just more freedom. Of course, you could also do this with well named branch names and a good team, but that’s more difficult. So often, people will just fall back to this workflow since it works so well—especially with GitHub which is such a pull request-centric platform anyway.

Comment: Thanks, the last three paragraphs were the answer that I was looking for! On a slightly related point, is there any particular reason why there is a distinction between  '___/grit' and '___/grit.git'?

Comment: @dant Incidentally, I just explained that yesterday in [an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46302984/216074) :)

Comment: fantastic! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit I see is that you can track your peers work by pulling theirs repository.

But sooner it will become a mess.

The most common workflow is using branches.

Normally, a team member doesn't need to keep pushing it's changes while working on a feature.

This is only needed if:

1. You want to keep a backup on the remote repo
2. You want to share the work with a peer
3. You want to resume work on a different computer

After work is done on your feature branch you then merge it to the main (master) branch.